# Find the smallest sequence of move needed to re-order rows according to an array

Tags: excel, vba, performance, optimization

I am working on a VBA script that sorts rows according to a couple of custom criteria. Since manipulating Excel rows is slow (big rows with various styles), I am doing the sorting through an object in memory:

1. Generate a jagged array representing the worksheet (containing only the relevant information used in the sorting process).
2. Sort the jagged array by applying a combination of quick-sort algorithm.
3. Regenerate the worksheet by using the sorted jagged array as a reference

Step 1 and 2 are only taking **0,84s** to proceed (for my biggest worksheet). But the last step, re-generating the excel worksheet, takes a very long time: **129,11s** in total !

Here is a simplified example of my code to regenerate the sheet:

```
Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = Worksheets("MySheet")
Dim EndRowIndex As Integer: EndRowIndex = WS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Dim Destination As Integer: Destination = EndRowIndex + 1 
Dim rowIndex As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To EndRowIndex 
  rowIndex = new_order_array(i)
  WS.Rows(rowIndex).Copy
  WS.Rows(destination).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'Copying the rows in the correct order at the bottom
  destination = destination + 1  'incrementing the destination row (so it stays at the bottom)
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
WS.Rows("1:"& endRowIdex ).Delete 'Deleting the old unordered rows from the sheet
```

( new_order_array was generated in step 2, it has as many element as there are rows in the worksheet. It indicate which row need to be moved where: new_order_array(1) = 3, means that the row 3 need to become the row 1. )

As you can see, this is a simple but naive re-ordering. I copy every row in the correct order at the bottom, then delete every unordered row at the top.

In order to fully optimize the process, I would need to re-order the worksheet by using the minimal number of moves. Currently, regenerating a worksheet of N rows requires **N** copy-pasting, while moving rows cleverly would required **at most N-1** moves. How can I find the smallest sequence of moves needed to re-order rows according to an array ?

I don't know were to begin my research for this task... are there existing algorithms on this subject ? Is this problem named (useful for keywords)? Did I miss something else that might improve performance (I have already disabled visual updates during the process)? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Suggest: 1) Read worksheet into a VBA Array (one step: `arr=range`). 2) Do all your sorting/filtering within the VBA array to create an output array that includes the entire range. 3) write the array back to the worksheet (again, one step: `range=arr`).

Comment: That's an interesting proposal, but it looks like some properties are lost when putting the range into an array. I have to keep the row styles and I need to be able to read their OutlineLevel property in the sorting process.

Comment: Yes, the method only preserves cell contents, not properties. Since it appears you'll need multiple worksheet writes, suggest you disable `ScreenUpdating`, `Calculation`, `Cursor`, `DisplayAlerts`, `EnableEvents`, `Interactive` and `StatusBar`, and see if that speeds things up enough. I don't know about your "minimum moves" problem, though.

Comment: Another thought: After you have a VBA array or collection with, let us say, the row numbers to be copy/pasted in the order you wish, execute the copy/paste in groups of contiguous rows.  That should cut down on the number of operations, depending on the results of the reordering.

Comment: `WS.Rows(new_order_array(i)).Copy` saves you `EndRowIndex` references.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly quick sorting algorithm in `n` steps.

The scrambled data:

```
'demo
Cells.Clear
Dim arr(1 To 100)
For i = 1 To 100
    arr(i) = i
Next i
'scramble
Randomize
Dim rarr(1 To 100)
x = 100
While x > 0
    r = Int(Rnd * x) + 1
    rarr(101 - x) = arr(r)
    arr(r) = arr(x)
    x = x - 1
Wend
For i = 1 To 100
    Cells(i, 1) = rarr(i)
Next i
```

The sort:

```
'sort
sp = 1 'start position
While sp < 101
    If rarr(sp) = sp Then
    WS.Rows(sp).Copy
    WS.Rows(destination).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    destination = destination + 1
    sp = sp + 1
    Else
    d = rarr(rarr(sp))
    rarr(rarr(sp)) = rarr(sp)
    rarr(sp) = d
    End If
Wend
For i = 1 To 100
    Cells(i, 2) = rarr(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

The `rarr` array has been restored.

It works by swapping the first element with the element at the first element's position, and repeats this until the correct element is in position, copy/pastes it, and then moves onto processing element 2, and continues like this through the whole array.

It is guaranteed to work (on a contiguous set of integers 1..k) because once an element is in it's correct position, it is not referenced again.